# Device Proximity LED for barcode

Tags: java, android, barcode, barcode-scanner

The fact is that old scanners do not read the generated 1D barcode from the phone screen. And I started looking for another option and came across [Beaming Barcode Technology](http://findevr.com/mobeam-barcode-beaming-technology-gains-broader-integration-samsung-pay/), and [here](http://findevr.com/mobeam-barcode-beaming-technology-gains-broader-integration-samsung-pay/).

I wanted to get the `SDK` for `Android`, I did not find it anywhere. I tried to decompile the old `APK`, to no avail.

After searching, I realized that they were bought by Samsung.

But for some reason they don’t talk about it anywhere, there are no questions in `StackOverflow` about this technology, or about the implementation of a smartphone Proximity sensor to generate a barcode.

Question:

Does this technology really work?

If so, how do you implement this yourself with a sensor?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the technology could be thought of as LoopPay(SamsungPay) in magnetic stripe cards.
[Samsung Paid Around $250 Million for LoopPay, Its Apple Pay Competitor](https://www.vox.com/2015/5/13/11562614/samsung-paid-around-250-million-for-looppay-its-apple-pay-competitor)
[Samsung Pay](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/app/samsung-pay)

The magnetic stripe card is highly compatible with the physical specifications regarding the reading method, and it was effective to some extent even with technologies such as LoopPay.
However, there may be countries or regions that are technically possible but are not serviced due to differences in rules or business practices.

On the other hand, the basics of barcode scanners are to illuminate a barcode and convert the light that can be reflected and detected to be recognized, but there are various methods and shapes.
[Mechanism of barcode scanning](https://www.denso-wave.com/en/adcd/fundamental/barcode/scan/index.html)

By analogy with LoopPay, isn't it a method of simulating this reflected light with the light emission of the LED of the smartphone and making it look like it has read a barcode?
The sensor is the barcode scanner of the POS terminal, so the sensor may not be needed on the smartphone side.

That's why there are no questions or articles about proximity sensors or any sensors.

However, as mentioned above, barcode scanners are not as limited in standards as magnetic stripe readers, and there are various methods and shapes of barcode scanners in the world.

The technology you asked may work, but if it works, it will have limited scope.
It is unlikely that it will spread in a practical range.